# Powermail, format output von powermail_all

Tags: typo3, powermail

TYPO3 7.6, actual version of powermail. The Output in confirmation page and receiver mail of checkboxen is devided by , - it looks like this:

my checkboxes:     option 1, option 2, option 3

etc. 
I need the options devided by new lines.

Is this possible? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using {powermail_all} to get the values of all fields, you have to change the Partial (originally stored under EXT:powermail/Resources/Private/Partials/PowermailAll/Web.html).